# NonUniqueObjectException: during cascading persist with jpa and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an entity A with 2 OneToOne relations on a second entity B.

```
entity   --  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)  -->  entity
   A     --  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)  -->     B
```

I want to manage the persistence from my entity A.

But when I call `em.persist(o)` hibernate throws the exception :

`org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [EntityB#null]`

As my entities are not persisted yet, their id are nulls. The equals and hashcode of EntityB are not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something to assign an id value to the B. Normally, you'd use [@GeneratedValue](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) to do that.

Comment: Ooops!! I forgot that my entityB has a @Embeddable id. That was my problem. Replacing it with a Long makes it working.